# Android editor Using Eclipse Link XML views to edit code and view graphic?

Tags: android, eclipse

hi I'm using Eclipse at the moment, and I'm not sure if there is a plug in for it or a better piece of software I can use. It seems fine for the Java side The problem I have is with XML editing, the line up of the characters is very inconsistent and when editing my layouts, I work with a graphic view open and a code view open, but the two are not linked, so if I double click on an element it switches from graphic view to code view in that pane. it would be awesome if I could link the two open panes?

Please see the screen shot for my desired outcome. [image]

*I understand that this question could be seen as discussion based, but I am seriously just looking for a solution here. The example I show is very simple, but some of the xml files turn out quite large and complex, and it is becoming more important to me to find a solution for this.*

Comment: To be sure not to get \infty close-votes, maybe change your title to something that implies you want to link the two views, and not just "want something better".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) for ui designing. Although it is a bit buggy, but at-least you dont need to edit raw xml files if you use this.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, its a start, but after using it for a bit, I find it much more cumbersome then my current method of using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using the Android eclipse Juno development kit, and while I still dont have dual window available, the double click select is working. there is also an Outline pane which shows the layout, although annoyingly this doesn't show comments very well.